# No distributions found at all for mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, pi-3, mysql

I tried to install mysql connector for python on Raspberrypi 3 but It didn't work,
I got an error message saying : No distributions found at all for mysql-connector python.
I usued the command:

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

I'm using python 2.7.9

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you always use packages from the official Raspbian repositories when possible.  They will have been tested and will be compatible with the other installed libraries.

`apt-cache search mysql | grep connect` shows a number of results.

For Python 2 use.

`sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector`

For Python 3 use.

`sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector`